# Modify an asp:BulletedList in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, bulletedlist

I've different buttons like this

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="single" title="single" EnableViewState="false" />
```

When this button is clicked I want that the text in a list like this changes

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="list1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
    <asp:ListItem>Item1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>
```

How in C# can I select the first, the second or the third element of the list?

```
protected button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list1. ...;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ListControl.Items Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items.aspx).

```
protected button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list1.Items[0] ...;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. I'm still improving my search skill for this kind of questione.

Comment: @user582693: You must accept an answer if you thought it answers your question, by clicking the tick to the left of the answer, which will turn green after click.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want to change you Item1 to dir, use this :

```
list1.Items[0].Attributes["class"] = "dir";
```